# export 'Learning' (imported as 'Learning') was not found in './Component/react' (possible exports: Learn)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]I am learning reactjs pls help me to fix this problem and pls tell my mistake as well as the solution
the error is Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 10:35-43

export 'Learning' (imported as 'Learning') was not found in './Component/react' (possible exports: Learn)

[image: img]

Comment: As the error message tells you, you're exporting `Learn` but you're trying to import `Learning`. `Learn` != `Learning`. Not sure what other information you need.

Comment: @tkausl how to fix that problem?

Comment: You fix it by either importing `Learn` or by exporting `Learning`. Choose __one__ name for the component.

Comment: @tkausl HELLO WORLD IS NOT PRINTING BUT ERROR IS GONE

Comment: I would use a function declaration* over a function expression and then `export default function Learn() {...}` and then `import Learn from './components/Learn', renaming `react.js` to `Learn.js`. *personal opinion

Comment: You forgot a `return`.

Comment: read more on the difference between named export and default export [here](https://javascript.info/import-export)

Answer (score 1):

Check name

Use `{ Learn }` instead of `{ Learning }`

Comment: HELLO WORLD IS NOT PRINTING BUT ERROR IS GONE